# Копирование формулы со смещением

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

В таблице три столбика - `A`, `B`, `C`.

В ячейки столбика `A` попадает сумма значений ячеек из столбиков `B` и `C`. Для этого в ячейке `A1` написана формула `=SUM(B1;C1)`, и далее эта формула легко протягивается в нижние строки и превращается в `=SUM(B2;C2)`, `=SUM(B3;C3)` и т.д.

Как это протягивание сделать с помощью скриптов?

Если я делаю

```
cellNew.setFormula(cellOld.getFormula);
```

, то формула копируется один в один, без смещения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Существует 4 основных способа копирования формул при помощи Google Apps Script:

1. Комбинирование методов  `getFormulas()/setFormulas()`
2. Использование универсального метода  `copyTo()`
3. Комбинирование методов `getFormulaR1C1()/setFormulaR1C1()`
4. Опосредованное применение комбинирования методов  `getFormulas()/setValues()`

### Рабочие варианты

```
// Универсальный метод
function universalMethod(sheet){
  var from = sheet.getRange("G3");
  var to = sheet.getRange("G4");
  var copyPasteType = SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA;
  var transposed = false;
  from.copyTo(to, copyPasteType, transposed);
}

// Комбинированный способ 2
function combinedMethod2(sheet){
  var from = sheet.getRange("H3");
  var to = sheet.getRange("H4");
  to.setFormulaR1C1(from.getFormulasR1C1());
}
```

### Решение задачи

```
// Пример с суммой
function sumExample(sheet){
  var from = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var to = sheet.getRange("A2:A");
  var copyPasteType = SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA;
  var transposed = false;
  from.copyTo(to, copyPasteType, transposed);
}
```

См. [Особенности копирования формул](https://googleappsscriptrc.blogspot.com/2018/07/copy-paste-formulas.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Протянуть формулу по столбцу
 * @param {string} sheetName название листа
 * @param {string} formulaStarCell ячейка с формулой, пример: "С2"
 * @param {string} [columnEndRow] столбец для поиска последней строки, пример: "B"
 */
function stretchFormula(sheetName, formulaStarCell, columnEndRow = null) {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  let lr;
  if (columnEndRow) {
    const lastRow = (sh, col) => {
      // до последней заполненной ячейки по конкретному столбцу
      const values = sh.getRange(col + ":" + col).getValues();
      return values.length - values.reverse().findIndex((row) => row[0] !== "");
    };
    lr = lastRow(sh, columnEndRow);
  } else lr = sh.getLastRow(); // до последней заполненной ячейки, по умолчанию

  sh.getRange(formulaStarCell)
    .activate()
    .autoFill(
      sh.getRange(
        `${formulaStarCell}:${formulaStarCell.replace(/\d/g, "")}` + lr
      ),
      SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES
    );
}
```